# Mocking Scala Trait using Scala, ScalaTest, and Mocktio

Tags: scala, mockito, scalatest

For whatever reason Mocktio will not mock a method I have in a trait, it will call the actual method. Here is my test:

```
"displays the index page" in {
  val mockAuth = mock[AuthMethods]
  when(mockAuth.isAllowed(-1, "", "")).thenReturn(true)
  val controller = new TestController()
  val result = controller.index().apply(FakeRequest())
  val bodyText = contentAsString(result)
  bodyText must include ("Name")
}
```

Here is the trait and object:

```
trait AuthMethods {
  def isAllowed(userID:Long, method:String, controller:String) : Boolean = {
     //do stuff..
  }
object Authorized extends AuthMethods with ActionBuilder [Request] {
  def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (Request[A]) => Future[Result]) = {
    if(isAllowed(userID, method, controller) {
       //do some more stuff..
  }
```

Any thoughts on why its calling the actual method verses the mocked method? I am using Scala 2.10.4. Any help would be appreciated.

I forgot to mention, Authorized is a Action Composition and here is how it is being used:

```
  def index = Authorized {
    Ok(html.Stations.index(Stations.retrieveAllStations))
  }
```

Comment: How does your `TestController` get its `AuthMethods` implementation?  Showing that code might help us anser.

Comment: @DonRoby I added how it is using the Authorized object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a mock implementation `mockAuth` but have not done anything with it.  Creating a mock implementation will not magically cause it to replace some other object.  It looks like you want to create a mock of the `Authorized` object and arrange for your TestController to use it.  You'll probably have to break a dependency somewhere.

(updated) Since this is in the context of the Play framework, you might find [this blog post](http://julien.richard-foy.fr/blog/2011/11/26/dependency-injection-in-scala-with-play-2-it-s-free/) helpful.  It describes a situation similar to yours.  It appears you will have to change the way the `Authorized` object is referenced in order to supply a mock implementation.

Comment: I updated my question to include where Authorized is being used. Does this answer still apply to the question?

Comment: I updated my answer with a useful (I hope) pointer to info that seems to match your situation.